# MVC: Html.ActionLink() Resolves to (Edit?Length=) instead of (Edit?Id=)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, actionlink

I have created an Admin area in my MVC 4 application. Under Views Folder called `UserManage`, I am using [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) to list out users (sets of 5) over several pages. In the Grid I am listing out the users details for viewing by Admin, and have added:

- A column containing a checkbox [ ].
- A column containing an `EDIT` link.
- A `CREATE` button.
- A `DELETE` button (to be used in conjunction with the checkbox for each row).

My User Details page is under my Admin Area in the following path: `Project\Areas\Admin\Views\UserManage\Index.cshtml`. On my `EDIT` liniks, I am attempting to pull up the view at `Project\Areas\Admin\Views\UserManage\Edit.cshtml` and pass the individual `UserID` to the View to pull up that users data.

In my current code below, my browser resolves to `http://localhost:62517/Admin/UserManage/Edit?Length=4` with an IIS 8.0 404 Error (*Controller cannot find UserID*). However if I manually change the `Length` to `Id` as follows,  everything works as intended and I end up on my `Edit` view: `http://localhost:62517/Admin/UserManage/Edit?Id=4`.

Here is my grid code for the `Index.cshtml` page. Does anyone know what I need to modify on my `Html.ActionLink()` so my route will resolved to `?Id=` instead of `?Length=`?:

```
<div class="overflowPrevention">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(o => @Html.CheckBox("checked", false));
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit", new { id = "1" }));

        }).AutoGenerateColumns()
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you indicate "Edit" as the controller name in your `Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit", new { id = "1" })` when your controller is called `UserManage`?

Comment: Actually, as I can see from the overloads, the one that matches your call signature would take "Edit" as the `object routeValues` which is also an IList<string> of Length 4 - maybe your issue could be related to this?

Comment: @chiccodoro, that could be the Length 4 issue. Thoughts to resolve?

Comment: You could fix that by adding `, null` to your call.

Comment: Or refresh this page and find Dismissile's answer which states about the same :-)

Comment: @chiccodoro, Dismissile definitely has me on the right path :) If you check my latest comment on his answer, I've got the path working, but my links now all say `UserManage` instead of `Edit`... (EDIT: We got it covered!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload.

```
@Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object htmlAttributes)
```

instead of

```
@Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

You can just pass null for htmlAttributes if you don't need to use them:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "UserManage", new { id = "1" }, null)
```

I'm not sure why you are using Edit, Edit, Edit though. I think that was a typo so I have changed it to use UserManage as the controller name.

Comment: Taking your suggestion I toyed with my overloads and the following yields a working path of `http://localhost:62517/Admin/UserManage/Edit/1` ==> `Html.ActionLink("UserManage", "Edit", new { id = "1" }, null)`. Though now my links are labeled as `UserManage` instead of `Edit`?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic The first parameter is the link text, not the controller. 1: Link Text, 2: Action, 3: Controller

Comment: that did it, thanks! :) Any ideas for how I would pass the individual UserId instead of '1'?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic I'm not sure what Grid builder you are using, but I'm sure if you check the docs for it you will be able to find out how.

Comment: Took some experimenting, but finally got it. `columns.Add(o => o.Id).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "UserManage", new { id = o.Id }, null));`; Thanks for all your help!